# c# generate key pair using ecdh prime256v1

Tags: c#, encryption, key-pair, ecdh, prime256v1

I'm making private/public key using ecdh

```
var ecdh = new ECDiffieHellmanCng(CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.ECDiffieHellmanP256, null, new CngKeyCreationParameters { ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport }));
var privateKey = ecdh.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob);
var publickey = ecdh.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
```

This code works fine, but I want to use Algorithm `prime256v1` and `CngAlgorithm` has no such option.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Aren't you using this already? From the  [CngAlgorithm.ECDiffieHellmanP256](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cngalgorithm.ecdiffiehellmanp256?view=netframework-4.8) description: `An object that specifies an ECDH algorithm that uses the P-256 curve.`

Comment: Check [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52883/ec-curve-selection) in crypto.stackexchange.com. It explains what this name means and where it came from.

Comment: So P256 = Prime256v1 ?

Comment: That's what the question and the linked source says - looks like bankers didn't want to use the same names as programmers so they defined their own curve IDs

Comment: thnank for the answer! :) Then I have to delete this question I guess :)

Comment: No, better leave it because other people will probably have the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, [CngAlgorithm.ECDiffieHellmanP256](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cngalgorithm.ecdiffiehellmanp256?view=netframework-4.8) specifies the P-256 curve :

> An object that specifies an ECDH algorithm that uses the P-256 curve.

This [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52886) in crypto.stackexchange.com explains what those names come from different sources and that P-256 in NIST notation corresponds to `prime256v1` in "ANSI X9.62 : Public Key Cryptography For The Financial Services Industry".

Comment: It’s also the same as `secp256r1` from the Standards for Efficient Cryptography (SEC) group.